# STM32 product line in a spreadsheet?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

There is a staggering number of variants of the STM32 family of MCUs.  I have been led to believe that a list of the available STM32 microcontroller parts and their various features is available somewhere in spreadsheet form.  Is this true and if so where can it be found?

Answer (score 2):

The [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) tool has an MCU selector module, that can export the product list and features in Excel format. It requires a bit of work to produce an usable spreadsheet, because you have to right-click on the table header, scroll down, and check every column you're interested in. Then click on the Excel icon to export it.

But if you have this tool, perhaps you don't need the spreadsheet at all.

The feature list is available as a .json file as well, it's at

```
~/.stmcufinder/plugins/mcufinder/mcu/mcusFeaturesAndDescription.json
```

on Linux systems, or in

```
\Program Files (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeMX\db\plugins\mcufinder\mcu\mcusFeaturesAndDescription.json
```

on Windows. Recent versions of Excel might be able to import it.

Comment: Note: That json file is a quite limited, and somewhat wrong view of the underlying data actually contains. For example, F215 isn't tagged for any encryption features.

In the same directory there's a zipped SQLite database file, cube-finder-db.db that has all the details and flags that STMCube itself actually displays, and even a bit more.

The schema is a bit odd to navigate, but not too hard.

Answer (score 1):

ST website used contain a product selector which enabled export to spreadsheet. At present they provide a downloadable MCU finder tool, capable of spreadsheet export.

Answer (score 0):

Full dataset of all the possible features for STM32 / STM8 is provided in "cube-finder-db.db" SQLite database file, that ships with STMCube. ( I'd guess superset of that same dataset is also used by ST.com product finders ) The file is at `STM32CubeMX/db/plugins/mcufinder/mcu/cube-finder-db.zip`

Use your favorite SQLite API or a tool like Sqlitebrowser to find every detail about the parts.

Sample how to list all STM32 chips with cores:

```
select rpn, cpn.cpn, cha.strValue, att.name
from cpn
join cpn_has_attribute cha on cha.cpn_id=cpn.id
join attribute att on att.id=cha.attribute_id
join rpn_has_cpn rhc on rhc.cpn_id=cpn.id
join rpn on rpn.id=rhc.rpn_id
where att.name='core'
order by strValue
```

More [elaborate example](https://gist.github.com/kaidokert/9adc8556ba09ec4f497975f6d23cfeb6) of how to find all the parts with any crypto features, which is far more convoluted than it ought to be.